# How to increase Apache CXF timeout using XML configuration and JaxWsProxyFactoryBean?

Tags: java, web-services, timeout, cxf, jax-ws

I am using `apache CXF` implementation of `JAX-WS`.
My web service is configured via `spring` xml configuration using `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`:

```
<bean id="myWSClient" class="my.package.MyWSClient"
      factory-bean="clientFactory" 
      factory-method="create" />

<bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="my.package.MyWSClient"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://some.url"/>
</bean>
```

and later I am injecting it via:

```
@Resource(name = "myWSClient")
MyWSClient myWSClient;
```

How I can manage to increase `timeout` for MyWSClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure client timeouts using `spring configuration` use this:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client
            ConnectionTimeout="600000"
            ReceiveTimeout="600000"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

In this example timeout for response and connection is setup for 600 seconds.

Reference:

- [Apache CXF: Client HTTP Transport: Advanced configuration](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-Theclientelement)

Answer (score 0):

You can add property **javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout** inside xml configuration. Value in millisecounds. 300000 millisecounds = 5 min

```
    <bean id="serviceServiceFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="pl.service.YourService"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://address:port/ws/YourService"/>
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout"><value>300000</value></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```